# Overriding properties in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In below code in test() method self.name is None. I'm expecting it as 'B- Stack'. Am I missing something?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = "A- " + value


class B(A):
    @A.name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = "B- " + value

    def test(self):
        print(self.name) # It should print B- Stack


b = B()
b.name = "Stack"
b.test()
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that double-underscored field not inherited. Try to add `_` to end of variable, e.g. `self.__name_`. In this case field become `protected` instead of `private`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are printing `self.name` which is setter method not actual `self.__name` .

Either you can add getter method or `print(self.__name)` in test method:

you can add getter method in B()

```
@name.getter
def name(self):
    return self.__name
```

Comment: print(self.__name) worked, @name.getter raised error 'Unresolved name reference'